# How to convert constraints to VFL

Tags: ios, ios-autolayout, autolayout

```
       NSLayoutConstraint *constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:label1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:label2 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:5];
```

I tried to write this code in VFL,but it seems the VFL only provide the NSLayoutFormatAlignAllTop property. So I can't set label1 is lower than label2 in 5 points.

I want to know if this constraint can't be written in VFL.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like,

```
  NSArray *verticalConstraints1 =[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-20-[label1]-20-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views];  // this set top and bottom vertical constraint

 NSArray *verticalConstraints1 =[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-20-[label1]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views];  // this will set only top

 NSArray *horizontalConstraints =[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-20-[label1]-20-[label2]-20-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]; //this will vertical constraint between two label and top and bottom to label1 and label2 respactively
```

You can refer [this link](http://www.knowstack.com/autolayout-visual-format-language-objective-c-sample-code/) for more details.

**Update :**

For example,

```
 |-[button1(button2)]-[button2]-|
```

This constraints means,  button1 must be the same width as button2, they have a standard spacing between them, button1 is a standard spacing from the left edge of the superview, and button2 is a standard spacing from the right edge of the superview.

If here you take `button1(button2/2)` then it's mean it's half width of button2. If you need this scenario in height manner then just add `V:` before statement.

another examle,

```
  V:|-(==padding)-[imageView]->=0-[button]-(==padding)-|
```

This constraints mean,

- The top of the image view must be padding points from the top of the
  superview
- The bottom of the image view must be greater than or equal to 0
  points from the top of the button
- The bottom of the button must be padding points from the bottom of
  the superview.

  ```
   |[button(==200@750)]-[label]|
  ```

This constrains means, The button’s width should be 200 points, with a priority of 750.

```
      |-30.0@200-[label]
```

The label should be spaced 30 points from the left of the superview, with a priority of 200.

In short you can set any type of constraints in `VFL` format.

Refer [this link as reference](http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2013/01/31/visual-format-language-for-autolayout/) for more details!

Hope this will help :)

Comment: seems the VFL can't define constraint like  view1 is half height of view2. or view1's top is behing view2'top 5 point. VFL can only define edge to edge constraint.

Comment: No, you can set every type of constraints by VFL. Do google and do some research

Comment: Could you show me some examples? I didn't find it so ask here.